# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el icono de la api de Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Me gustaría saber como poder cambiar el icono de ubicación de la api de Google maps, por el de una imagen, para cada una de las localizaciones marcadas pero sin embargo lo he intentado y no puedo, el mapa simplemente desaparece o no cambia nada de los marcadores.

```
function iniciarMap(){
  var locations = [
    ['Santamarta', 11.2288704, -74.1983795, 'Av. Del Ferrocarril #29-565 a 29-489, Santa Marta, Magdalena', '123456789', '<img src="img/SANTA MARTA/El_Overol_Santa_Marta.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Barranquilla', 10.9897276, -74.8045349, 'Cra. 43 ## 69-112, Barranquilla, Atlántico', '3174285751', '<img src="img/BARRANQUILLA/El_Overol_Cartagena_Almacen.jpg" width="200" >'],
    ['Cartagena', 10.3751669, -75.5042101, 'Centro Empresarial Bloc Port Local 43, Cra 56 #7C-39 Km1, Cartagena, Distrito Turístico Y Cultural, Bolívar', '316 7458495', '<img src="img/CARTAGENA/El_Overol_Cartagena_Almacen.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Mosquera', 4.7093862, -74.2160548, 'Cra. 5 Este #20-69, Mosquera, Cundinamarca', '3167458495', '<img src="img/MOQUERA/El_Overol_Mosquera_Almacen.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Bogota', 4.665837, -74.065202, 'Ak. 24 #75-2 a 75-60, Bogotá', '318 735 8177', '<img src="img/BOGOTA/EL OVEROL ALCAZARES/El_Overol_Alcazares_Almacen.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Bogota', 4.7499709, -74.0473062, 'AUTOPISTA NORTE 168 #43, Bogotá', '+5712779854', '<img src="img/BOGOTA/EL OVEROL AUTONORTE/EL_Overol_Autonorte_Almacen.jpg" width="200" >'],
    ['Buecaramanga', 7.1224875,-73.1211944, 'Cl. 33 #22-2 a 22-88, Bucaramanga, Floridablanca, Santander', '3174398131', '<img src="img/BUCARAMANGA/El_Overol_Bucaramanga_Almacen.jpg" witch="200" >'],
    ['Bogota', 4.1458941, -73.6317997, 'Cl. 31 #27-139 a 27-3, Villavicencio, Meta', '+5716952383', '<img src="img/BOGOTA/EL OVEROL ALCAZARES/El_Overol_Alcazares_Almacen.jpg" width="200">']
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(4.66, -74.13),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;


    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(`<b>${ locations[i][0] }</b><br><b>Dirección:</b> ${ locations[i][3] }<br><b>Teléfono:</b> ${ locations[i][4] }<br><center>${ locations[i][5] }</center>`);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo lo siguente:

```
function iniciarMap(){
  var locations = [
    ['Santamarta', 11.2288704, -74.1983795, 'Av. Del Ferrocarril #29-565 a 29-489, Santa Marta, Magdalena', '123456789', '<img src="img/SANTA MARTA/El_Overol_Santa_Marta.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Barranquilla', 10.9897276, -74.8045349, 'Cra. 43 ## 69-112, Barranquilla, Atlántico', '3174285751', '<img src="img/BARRANQUILLA/El_Overol_Cartagena_Almacen.jpg" width="200" >'],
    ['Cartagena', 10.3751669, -75.5042101, 'Centro Empresarial Bloc Port Local 43, Cra 56 #7C-39 Km1, Cartagena, Distrito Turístico Y Cultural, Bolívar', '316 7458495', '<img src="img/CARTAGENA/El_Overol_Cartagena_Almacen.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Mosquera', 4.7093862, -74.2160548, 'Cra. 5 Este #20-69, Mosquera, Cundinamarca', '3167458495', '<img src="img/MOQUERA/El_Overol_Mosquera_Almacen.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Bogota', 4.665837, -74.065202, 'Ak. 24 #75-2 a 75-60, Bogotá', '318 735 8177', '<img src="img/BOGOTA/EL OVEROL ALCAZARES/El_Overol_Alcazares_Almacen.jpg" width="200">'],
    ['Bogota', 4.7499709, -74.0473062, 'AUTOPISTA NORTE 168 #43, Bogotá', '+5712779854', '<img src="img/BOGOTA/EL OVEROL AUTONORTE/EL_Overol_Autonorte_Almacen.jpg" width="200" >'],
    ['Buecaramanga', 7.1224875,-73.1211944, 'Cl. 33 #22-2 a 22-88, Bucaramanga, Floridablanca, Santander', '3174398131', '<img src="img/BUCARAMANGA/El_Overol_Bucaramanga_Almacen.jpg" witch="200" >'],
    ['Bogota', 4.1458941, -73.6317997, 'Cl. 31 #27-139 a 27-3, Villavicencio, Meta', '+5716952383', '<img src="img/BOGOTA/EL OVEROL ALCAZARES/El_Overol_Alcazares_Almacen.jpg" width="200">']
  ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(4.66, -74.13),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var img = "https://ruta_de_imagen_aqui.png";

    var marker, i;


    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map,
          icon: img
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(`<b>${ locations[i][0] }</b><br><b>Dirección:</b> ${ locations[i][3] }<br><b>Teléfono:</b> ${ locations[i][4] }<br><center>${ locations[i][5] }</center>`);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
  }
}
```